# 2 Таблицы из БД обновляются и выводят результат на страницу сайта только после обновления! Почему?? Кнопки Like / DisLike

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, like

Доброго времени суток всем! Вопрос в заголовке. Да к тому же и страницу сайта нужно обновить, чтобы появился последний результат (каждый клик по кнопке, это +1 к предыдущему результату).  Помогите, кто может?!  :)

Привожу пример для одной кнопки, допустим:  Like.

`index.php`

// Счётчик кликов с сохранением в БД
`require_once('counter.php');`  // обработчик кнопок Like / DisLike

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=название БД;charset=utf8";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'имя пользователя БД', 'password', $опционально);

  $statement = $pdo->query("SELECT `value` FROM counterLike WHERE `idLike` = 1");
  $like = (int)$statement->fetchColumn();
```

Дальше форма HTML ................. не существенно, т.к. не в ней проблема.

`main.js`

```
<script>
       // Клик по кнопке Like
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var linklike = $("#btnLike"),
            counterlike = $("#like_count"),
            countlike = 0;

        // Блок - Лайк ( Like )
        linklike.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var ajax = $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'https://site.php/counter.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {
                    'countlike': 1
                }
            });
            ajax.done(function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                counterlike.html(parseInt(data));
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

`counter.php`

```
<?php
  declare(strict_types=1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  // конфигурация БД
$servername = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'название БД';   
$database = 'имя пользователя БД';   
$password = 'password';    

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=название БД;charset=utf8"; 
  
try {  
      $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'имя пользователя БД', 'password', $опционально);
        // Для таблице counterLike
    if (isset($_POST['countlike']) && (int)$_POST['countlike'] === 1) {
        $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT `value` FROM counterLike WHERE `idLike` = 1");  // Для Like
        $like = (int)$stmt->fetchColumn();
        $like++;
   $paramsLike = [
     ':id' => 1,
     ':value' => $like  
   ];
   $query = "UPDATE `counterLike` SET `value` = :value WHERE `idLike` = :id";
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
   $stmt->execute($paramsLike); 
     echo json_encode($like);  
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
 } 
?>
```

И вот последний результат SQL-таблицы "counterLike" в БД:
[image: последний результат SQL-таблицы "counterLike"]

Прошу Вашей помощи!

Comment: `ajax.done` поставьте в первый ajax

Comment: Хотелось бы по конкретней ... Можете в коде показать?

Answer (score 0):

У вас к моменту завершения выполнения ajax ещё не подцепился обработчик результата заброса или атрибут `done` в ajax не существует (я по документации не нашёл), его нужно заменить на `success` следующим образом:

```
var ajax = $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://site.php/counter.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        'countlike': 1
    },
    success: function (data) {
         counterlike.html(data);
    },
});
```

Замените  `echo json_encode($like);` в php скрипте на `echo $like;`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: ArchDemon,  спасибо за внимание! Но, не помогло ... Проблема осталась. После клика на одну из кнопок Like / DisLike, клики не увеличиваются на 1. пока не обновлю страницу. Тоже самое и на странице с таблицами БД. Пока не обновлю phpMyAdmin, клики в таблицах не увеличиваются на +1.

Comment: @Самоучка, обновил ответ

Comment: echo $like;  Вместо  echo json_encode($like);  поставил, но результат тот же... Только после обновления браузера, отображаются клик +1 и так же и в таблицах phpMyAdmin

Comment: Перед `counterlike.html(data);` поставьте `console.log(data);` и посмотрите что браузер в консоль выведет

Comment: Да, спасибо Вам!